# Everywhere defined functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose A has 4 elements and B has 3 elements.
(a) How many everywhere defined functions are there from A to B? I tried the Pigeonhole principle but I got fraction. Please assist.

Comment: If $a\in A$ then how many choices are there for $f(a)\in B$? And how many times can a choice like that be made?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that every element in $A$ has $3$ choice $\implies$ $3^{|A|}=3^4$ possible choices in total.

In general; The number of the function from $A$ to $B$ is $|B|^{|A|}$ with same reasoning.